# php dynamic table display

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, phpmyadmin, dynamic-data

I have a returned multi dimensional array from my DB, looking something like this

```
   $prices = array();

    /*some SQL coding */
print_r($prices);
        Array
    (
          [0]
              [id] => 1
              [title] => XT1 Comp
              [young] => 50
              [mid] => 50
              [old] => 120
          [1]
              [id] => 2
              [title] => HH3 Enginee
              [young] => 150
              [mid] => 170
              [old] => 220
    )
```

So far so good. But how best to print this as a dynamic table ? Am  a little stuck and any hint is greatly aprpeciated

I hope someone can help. I am hoping for a outpus like this:

```
id | title     | young| mid| old
1  |  XT1 Comp | 50   | 50 | 120
and so one for each row / array index or line
```

Kind regards
Alex

EDIT -> this is how i get them.

```
$result_array = array();
        while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
            $result_array[] = $line;
        }

        return $result_array
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a php foreach to output each of the items in `$prices`:

```
<?php
function queryResultAsTable($results) {
    if(count($results) == 0) {
        echo '<em>No rows returned</em>';
    } else {
        echo '<table><thead><tr><th>'.implode('</th><th>', array_keys(reset($results))).'</th></tr></thead><tbody>'."\n";

        foreach($results as $result) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', array_values($result)).'</td></tr>'."\n";
        }

        echo '</tbody></table>';
    }
}

queryResultAsTable($prices);
```

Comment: this little nice function made me change who I accept. Shame I cant give you both the same amount of credit . .

Comment: How can you edit this function, in order to have each row each value in an editable input field ??? that be amazing !!

Comment: @AlexanderGrosse It is possible with Javascript. It's called "in place editing" and you'll probably want to use a JS library like JQuery to do the heavy lifting. And there are lots of plug 'n play in place extensions like [jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) already available.

Answer (score 2):

use a loop:

```
foreach( $prices as $row ) {
    echo '|' . $row['id'] . '|' . $row['title'] . '|' . $row['young'] . '|';
    echo '|' . $row['mid'] . '|' . $row['old'] . '|';
}
```

It will go through each row and allow you to access each column value.

EDIT:

If you are using `mysql_query();` to get the results then after you use it use the following:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $query_result ) ) {
    // Same echo stuff here
}
```

Comment: that does the job ? for each "array name" as row. So I assume that as $row = array index/line with all its values. So once it reaches value for "old" e.g. the $row ends, starting new one if exists !

Comment: Exactly. It loops through each row. Once it finishes with the last it exits the loop.

Comment: sorted then, thx man. No idea why i got stuck on that one ;p legend !